# bash install with group that does not exist

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a linux installation script, where I boot into a RAM disk image of linux and then install the new version of linux to flash on a mount.

The RAM disk (running) version of linux does not have a user group called "bob", but the image I have installed on the mounted partition *does*.

The installation completes, but one of the last steps I want to do is create a couple of folders that are owned by the group "bob"

So I use do something like:

```bash
# Note: /tmp/test is not the actual mount point - this is just an example
install -o user -g bob -d /tmp/test
install: invalid group ‘bob’
```

My current running version of linux does not have the group bob, but I know that the target folder I am creating does have this group - when I reboot into that image.

Is there a way to do this? The only thing I can think of is to create the group "bob" temporarily, do the `install` command and then delete it again.

Comment: Does the `install` command allow you to specify the numeric group ID instead of a group name? If so, replace `bob` with the GID.

Comment: Why not [groupadd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/groupadd.8.html) ?

Comment: @Barmar yes it does - but I don't know I can gurantee what the ID will be - its assigned automatically within bitbake when I create the image and may change.

Comment: @JRFerguson - that is what I was suggesting for my hacky workaround - but I don't really want to add/remove the group to the running version of linux - the installed version (on the mount point I am adding the folder to) already has the group...

Comment: Even if you create the group temporarily, the group ID won't match the ID in the image, so you'll use the wrong ID when installing. You need some way of extracting bob's ID from the image.

Comment: @Barmar ahhh.... that's a good point. I guess I can read out the ID from the `/etc/group` file on the installed image.... that should work, will give it a go. In the meantime you can put that and your first comment as the answer : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract bob's GID from the `/etc/group` file in the mounted image, and use that.

I think you also need to do the same thing for the UID if `user`, since that may not be the same as in the host system.

```
uid=$(awk -F: '$1 == "user" {print $3}' /tmp/test/etc/passwd)
gid=$(awk -F: '$1 == "bob" {print $3}' /tmp/test/etc/group)
if [ -n "$uid" && -n "$gid" ]
then
    install -o "$uid" -g "$gid" -d /tmp/test
fi
```